# How to recursivly use JpegTran (command line) to optimise all files in subdirs?

Tags: macos, bash, command-line, operating-system, jpeg

i have Photos in multiple directories. I want to use jpegtran (command line tool) to recursivly go through each one, optimise it, and save it (overwrite it)

if they are all in one folder i use this

```
for JPEG in *.jpg ; do jpegtran -optimize $JPEG > $JPEG; done
```

but i can't get it working recursivly and overwriting the same file (rather than to a new filename)

any tips?

Answer (score 25):

[jpegtran whole directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15835351/jpegtran-whole-directory)

```
find /the/image/path -name "*.jpg" -type f -exec jpegtran -copy none -optimize -outfile {} {} \;
```

Answer (score 5):

How about using the `find` command:

```
find /your/dir -name '*.jpg' -exec echo jpegtran -optimize {} \;
```

Run the command, if you like the output, remove `echo` to execute it.

Comment: jpegtran has default output on stdout.

Answer (score 3):

It is usually a whole lot easier to use **find** in such cases, because what you want to do is *act* on a few filenames. The **find** utility will give you those names. Assuming you have GNU (or maybe even BSD) tools, the following example will illustrate this common scenario.

For example:

```
$ find ~/images/wallpapers/TEMP/ -type f -iname '*jpg' \
    -exec sh -c 'jpegtran -outfile {}.out -optimize {}; mv {}.out {} ' \;
```

1. **find** looks for all files ending with jpg in the TEMP folder, recursively.
2. For every *full file path* found (denoted by `{}'), **find** will run the command given to -exec
3. the -exec option cheats and runs several commands instead of one through **sh**

***Notes***

`cat file > file` is not allowed because simultaneously reading from, and writing to the same file is not a well defined or even supported operation in **bash**.

Answer (score 0):

**Talking about Python approach:**

Firstly make an list of all of your paths.

Then:

```
import subprocess
for path in paths:
    for image_name in arr:
            subprocess.call(["jpegtran", "-your", "-instructions"])
```

Let's say your instruction is something like:

`jpegtran -optimize -progressive -scans script_new.txt -outfile progressive.jpg original.jpg`

So your instruction will be like:

```
subprocess.call(["jpegtran", "-optimize", "-progressive", "-scans", f"{scan_name}.txt", "-outfile", name_progressive, name_original])
```

For your convenience, name_progressive, name_original and scan_name are variables and concept f-string is used.